# How To Automatically Edit Request Parameters In Burp Suite

Tags: windows-10, security, kali-linux, web-application

How can I edit the parameters from the requests that burp suite intercepts and forward them automatically. Like for example in the below snap I want to edit the `User-Agent` line to some other browse name and operating system. I want to do this for every request it forwards. Yes, that can be done manually by editing each request and forwarding it but that's time consuming.

[image: raw output showing details]

Answer (score 0):

The proxy->options window's match and replace feature is probably what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Match and Replace" functionality of the Burp Suite proxy.
Navigate to "Proxy -> Options -> Match and Replace" option.

Now add a new rule for automatic match and replace for all the requests,
Enable the new rule with the checkbox.

[image]

After that, just navigate to any URL in your browser to get new requests.
Observe the new Requests with the match and replace rule applied.

[image]